# Unable to use .Any() for generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in controller, i am calling a service operation, which would return List

i want to use response.Customers.Any() , as i would be looking for specific customers. but sometimes .Any() is not there. it give a compile error when i use .Any().

not sure if it would depend on the way i call the operation? because i always thought that we can use .Any() for Generic list

Controller

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(ICustomerService customerService) 
    {
        this.CustomerService = customerService;
    }

     private ICustomerService CustomerService { get; set; }

    var response = this.ExecuteServiceCall(() => this.CustomerService.getCustomerResults());

    response.customers.Any(x => x.group == "A");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` is an extension method for the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, but its implementation resides in the static `Enumerable` class in the `System.Linq` namespace. It looks something like this:

```
using System;
namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class Enumerable
    {
        ...

        public static bool Any<TSource>(
            this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (predicate(item))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

You need to add a `using System.Linq;` statement if you want to use it as an extension method.

Alternatively, for your understanding, you could call it as

```
bool b = System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(response.customers, x => x.group == "A");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included System.Linq in your class to be able to use .Any()

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the namespace `System.Linq` first.

Then, if your `response.customers`

- Implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you should be good to go.
- *Explictly* implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll need to cast it to the desired interface:

  ```
  bool hit = ((IEnumerable<Customer>)(response.customers))
             .Any( x => x.group == "A" )
             ;
  ```
- Doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`, you'll need to cast it differently:

  ```
  bool hit = response.customers
             .Cast<Customer>()
             .Any( x => x.group == "A" )
             ;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Is the customers list a property of the object returned, or is it the object itself? Would something like this work?

```
var customers = this.ExecuteServiceCall(() => this.CustomerService.getCustomerResults());

if (customers.Any(c => c.group == "A")
{
    . . .
}
```